# CPU load steadily increasing and MySQL 1.5 GB open deleted file in temp directory

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, cpu-usage

I have a CentOS server that is running cPanel (shared hosting server), I have had troubles with MySQL before and I spent some time configuring and tuning it, until finally the load dropped (from 170%!! to 10% or so), until 2 days ago when MySQL started acting all crazy!

The server got "stuck", Apache and MySQL specifically! I logged and checked the `/tmp` directory with `df` and it was using 100% of the available space (2 GB), I ran `du -h` and it reported only 129 MB used space! I had no idea where is the other space gone, I tried `lsof +L1` to see open files and it listed a whole bunch of open deleted files in the temp directory (most of them had 0 size) except for one owned by MySQL which had 1.5 GB, I killed the process and the space was freed.

I did not know what that file is as I don't know how to access it so what did cause this file? And what should `lsof +L`` usually output? is this output normal?

```
httpd    6450 nobody  559w   REG    8,2        0     0 2492169 /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex (deleted)
httpd    6450 nobody  560u   REG    8,4        0     0     151 /tmp/ZCUDj2EaZi (deleted)
httpd    6490 nobody  559w   REG    8,2        0     0 2492169 /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex (deleted)
httpd    6490 nobody  560u   REG    8,4        0     0     151 /tmp/ZCUDj2EaZi (deleted)
httpd    6528 nobody  559w   REG    8,2        0     0 2492169 /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex (deleted)
httpd    6528 nobody  560u   REG    8,4        0     0     151 /tmp/ZCUDj2EaZi (deleted)
mysqld  46096  mysql    4u   REG    8,4        0     0     141 /tmp/ibvvhkQX (deleted)
mysqld  46096  mysql    5u   REG    8,4      432     0     143 /tmp/ibrHhJ9J (deleted)
mysqld  46096  mysql    6u   REG    8,4        0     0     144 /tmp/ibsWv8sw (deleted)
mysqld  46096  mysql    7u   REG    8,4        0     0     145 /tmp/ibjEeVSi (deleted)
mysqld  46096  mysql   17u   REG    8,4        0     0     146 /tmp/ibFo67JJ (deleted)
httpd   47389   root  559w   REG    8,2        0     0 2492169 /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex (deleted)
httpd   47389   root  560u   REG    8,4        0     0     151 /tmp/ZCUDj2EaZi (deleted)
```

There are like 100 files but it's not like I'm gonna post it all.

It's not a heavily loaded server and it is even VERY powerful for the websites it serves, so this surely is a mis-configuration or a bug problem, here is my server's information:

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz/ 8MB cache
RAM: 16 GB
OS: CENTOS 6.4
MySQL: 5.1.68

Sometimes MySQL's CPU usage is reaching over 100%, steadily increasing while `mysqladmin show processlist` is only showing few processes, and this is my my.cnf file:

```
max_connections=500
innodb_file_per_table=1
local-infile=0
slow_query_log
key_buffer_size=2G
query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_size=32M
join_buffer_size=2M
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
thread_cache_size=4
table_cache=256
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
```

And one important thing to mention is, the swap is being used sometimes while I still have plenty of free physical RAM, and I think this should not happen.

For some reason I think the server is sometimes having some DoS attacks, I don't know if that is related but I know this cos sometimes when I ran netstat I see some IPs with 250 open connections (and these are not search engine bots), if I block these IPs new IPs will start connecting and again 100 - 200 open connections from one IP.

Sorry if I made this longer than it needs to be, but I want to know how to troubleshoot this problem, mainly about the large MySQL temp file and the "steadily" increasing load.

Thanks.

Comment: I also wanted to ask, I was going to add a cron job that checks to see if there is any >1GB file opened by MySQL and restart MySQL so this does not happen again, temporarily until I find the solution, so is this safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to upgrade MySQL to latest version.

> mysql_upgrade --force

replace `slow_query_log` with `log-slow-queries=/var/lib/mysql/slow.log` in my.cnf

then execute commands

> touch /var/lib/mysql/slow.log
>   
>   chmod 660 /var/lib/mysql/slow.log
>   
>   chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/slow.log

Remove `innodb_file_per_table=1` from my.cnf too.

You can install CSF Firewall if you doubt you are under DDoS attack:

http://configserver.com/free/csf/install.txt